# Unable to get the metadata into list when trying to populate data from csv file using powershell into list

Tags: powershell

I was trying to import the csv file with 5500 items in it and it is also having metadata items when i try to use powershell script to populate the data from csv to list everything is showing in list except the metadata items column is blank.Unable to get the metadata items into list please help me out in this regard.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the answer solved the problem statet in your question, you should mark this answer as accepted answer to help future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

There's a post by Paul Childs that maybe of similar interest (file upload with metadata using PowerShell) -[Bulk upload files with metadata into SharePoint using PowerShell](http://get-spscripts.com/2010/10/bulk-upload-files-with-metadata-into.html)

Another post (in C#) - [Updating Managed Metadata Column Values (TaxonomyField)](http://www.3guysonsharepoint.com/?p=1052)

Comment: @ sbc111 ..Thanks for the blogs it helped me alot...:-)

Comment: Vikram: you are welcome - post back here if you have any more questions, etc..

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link is broken, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Benny - the post was ~2 years ago. I'll update the post shortly. Thanks.

Comment: @SupriyoSBChatterjee Super. We're cleaning the archives at the moment. Join us if you want to http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1003/cleaning-the-archives?cb=1